# Twig does not render just anything

Tags: php, twig

I have problems since I've upgraded PHP on my server to version 7.1.8 from 5.6.something.
Twig engine just does not want to render anything. Even the basic array example. It just returns the plain text of the page. Currently I am using Twig version 2.4.4, but I have noticed that it was doing the same with previous that I had - version 1.something.
There is no error, no notice, nothing, just it returns the plain text of the template.
Can you give me an idea where can I look and is there any specific setting of PHP that I have to adjust?

Comment: Check the response code from server also do check server error logs

Comment: Can you share you code or your config ?

Comment: There is nothing strande in the headers and nothing in the server error log.

Comment: http://mihailangelov.com/php.ini.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've found the problem!
In PHP version 7.1.8 there is a problem with PCRE library.
It uses outdated 8.38 version internaly.
I don't know what is the exact problem but I've found that it has execution problem with complex search patterns.
I had problems with PHPMailer too and I found that it's not evaluating perfectly valid host mach regex.

I've solved all of my problems by updating PHP to the latest version.